# Guardar audio en base de datos MySQL

Tags: android

mi nombre es Gonzalo y estoy iniciándome en ésto del desarrollo de aplicaciones móviles para android. El tema es que me encargaron hacer una app que grabe audios y que estas se guarden en una base de datos, para que después sean reproducidos de manera aleatoria. Ya logré que se graben audios pero estos se almacenan de manera temporal solo en el teléfono:

El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener {
    TextView tv1;
    MediaRecorder recorder;
    MediaPlayer player;
    File archivo;
    TextView b1, b2, b3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        b1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.escuchar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void grabar(View v) {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath());
        try {
            archivo = File.createTempFile("temporal", ".3gp", path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        recorder.setOutputFile(archivo.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        recorder.start();
        tv1.setText("Grabando");
        b1.setEnabled(false);
        b2.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public void detener(View v) {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        try {
            player.setDataSource(archivo.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        try {
            player.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        b1.setEnabled(true);
        b2.setEnabled(false);
        b3.setEnabled(true);
        tv1.setText("Listo para reproducir");
    }

    public void escuchar(View v) {
        player.start();
        b1.setEnabled(false);
        b2.setEnabled(false);
        b3.setEnabled(false);
        tv1.setText("Reproduciendo");
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        b1.setEnabled(true);
        b2.setEnabled(true);
        b3.setEnabled(true);
        tv1.setText("Listo");
    }
}
```

Desde ya agradezco sus respuestas.

Comment: Deberías guardar en la base de datos solo la referencia a la ubicación del archivo de audio y el audio subirlo a un servidor de almacenamiento.

Comment: Me podías dar un ejemplo por favor. Gracias.